# Use keyof on optional field

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to use keyof to describe the parameters of a function, based on an optional field in a Object.
And I would like to add a default value.

```
interface foo {
  bar?: {
     opt1: string,
     opt2: string
  }
}

function func(option: keyof foo["bar"] = "opt1") ...
```

But as `bar` is optional i got `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of the possibility of `undefined` by using `NonNullable`:

```
function func(option: keyof NonNullable<foo["bar"]> = "opt1")
```

Note that the above will also get rid of the possibility of `null`, which may or may not be desired. Another option is you could use `Exclude`, which is more verbose but gives you more flexibility:

```
function func(option: keyof Exclude<foo["bar"], undefined> = "opt1")
```

For more info on these utility types, see this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for the so fast awnser !